# Using lambdas LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am still in the midst of converting our web app from vb to C# and this complex query, that I just finished converting and have tested and it works properly, needs refactoring.

This section could probably perform a little better if lambdas were used (I've read in numerous places that lambda expressions perform faster)

```
 foreach (var datapersymbol in (from symId in symblist
                select (
                    from q in ctx.HistoricalPriceData.Where(q => q.SymbolId == symId)
                    join x in ctx.Symbols on q.SymbolId equals x.SymbolId
                    orderby q.Date descending
                    select new {q.Date, q.LastPrice, x.Symbol1})).ToList())
```

As you can see I've added lambdas where I thought appropriate but Im certain they can be in other parts of this expressions as well. I'm still getting up to speed in C# so Im not an expert here.

Comment: Are you querying a database with EF, or in memory objects? Do your HistoricalPriceData and Symbol objects have relational objects between each other, or are they just two lists with "matching" IDs.

Comment: For starts, you better do not define two different `q`s, it is hard to read and can introduce scoping problems.

Comment: there are similar extension methods present which you can use like `JOIN()` for join but that's not entirely correct that lamda expression way gives performance boost. the only difference is SQL like form behind the scene generate a lamda expression so if you write it in lambda then that step is waived off but Even MSDN says there is no observable performance difference.

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: What is the `ToList()` in there for, if you just `foreach` through it? There can be cases where it has a useful effect, but for the most part that's just going to slow things down for no gain.

Comment: @krillgar...There is no navigational property between the two, meaning there is no symbol entity as part of HistoricalPriceData, just a symbolId property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a navigation property on HistoricalPriceData to Symbols called "Symbol":

```
foreach(var datapersymbol in ctx
  .HistoricalPriceData
  .Where(h=>symblist.Contains(h.SymbolId))
  .OrderByDescending(h=>h.Date)
  .Select(h=>new {h.Date,h.LastPrice,h.Symbol.Symbol1}))
```

As Rahul pointed out, there is no performance difference between lamda/method syntax and query syntax, however, this will perform slightly better because it drops the .ToList(), which will allow the loop to begin processing as soon as it gets the first record from the database rather than waiting for the entire result (and it doesn't need to create a List).  I've also simplified it somewhat by using .Contains instead of a subquery as well, and switched to using navigation properties rather than a explicit join which makes it easier to read/more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

For the clarity of the code I will rather refactor it like below;

```
var datapersymbols  = from symId in symblist
                     select (
                from q in ctx.HistoricalPriceData.Where(q => q.SymbolId == symId)
                join x in ctx.Symbols on q.SymbolId equals x.SymbolId
                orderby q.Date descending
                select new {q.Date, q.LastPrice, x.Symbol1});

foreach (var datapersymbol in datapersymbols)
{
}
```

As far as I can see, in this case, there is not much that you can gain from the C# side. You have to check the query plan for the SQL query and then add necessary indexes. The `SymbolId` field should be an indexed field.